# Can we move a question from Stack Overflow to another Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, questions, migration

Would it be possible to move a question from one Stack Exchange site to another? If yes, what would happen with answers and votes assigned to that question?

Comment: [What is migration and how does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes.

A user with 3,000 rep can vote to migrate a question to another site. Any user can flag a question and ask a moderator to move it to another site. Before you vote to migrate a question or ask a moderator to do it, be sure that the other site is appropriate for the question. (aka read the FAQ).

When a question is migrated, all downvotes are cleared and all answers are deleted on the origin site. They are moved to the new site. Any rep lost or gained from the answers is reversed. Generally you don't vote to migrate an question that has a good answer, because then the question's purpose is served. There is no reason to move it to another site so it can get an answer.

Full information in the Meta Stack Exchange here: [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: Is it true that the options for migration are limited? I want to migrate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981314/handling-async-exception-from-non-async-caller to codereview.stackexchange.com, but that doesn't appear to be one of the options when voting to close the question as off-topic.

Comment: So If I ask about Fishing for Mackerel on Stack Overflow, and it gets a great answer, instantly, it can't be migrated to another site? It has to stay because it's "served its purpose"?

Comment: @n00dles is there a site where that'd be on topic?

Comment: @KevinB Unless fishing is a [sport](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51/what-is-counted-as-sport), then I'm not sure if it would fit anywhere.

Answer (score 10):

I was warned before about a 60 days limitation for migration requests. I was told that questions older than 60 days won't be migrated.