# Can I myself move my own question to another site?

Tags: support, migration, migrated-questions

I posted a question on Stack Overflow and after a discussion with other users I noticed that it would fit better on Super User (it's about FTP hosts so it's at the limit between programming and computer software). Is there a way that I can move my own question to Super User myself? I know that I can flag it, but other people have already done that. In case it matters, I have an account both on Stack Overflow and Super User.

Is there a way to myself move my own question to another site? Or is the only way to do it to flag it so that a moderator does it?

Comment: no, you can't do it yourself.

Comment: @sevenseacat Do I need to flag my own question then? And is there a reason why I can't do it myself?

Comment: @Stijn No, not exactly. That question asks if a question can be moved at all, and I'm asking if I can move it myself already knowing that moderators can. The questions are similar, but not exactly the same.

Comment: @DonaldDuck It explains the different ways of how a question can be moved. Since it doesn't say that you can move it all by yourself, it answers your question.

Comment: Of course you can do it yourself. Delete the question on Stack Overflow and repost it on Super User. There's no need to ask someone else to do it for you.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I can't delete the question since it has an up-voted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Can we move a question from Stack Overflow to another Stack Exchange site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270039/can-we-move-a-question-from-stack-overflow-to-another-stack-exchange-site)

> A user with 3,000 rep can vote to migrate a question to another site. Any user can flag a question and ask a moderator to move it to another site.

Although it doesn't explicitly state that you cannot migrate a question all by yourself, one can deduce that it's not possible to do this.

Comment: Is there a reason why I can't move my own question to another site?

Comment: @DonaldDuck Probably to prevent mistakes and abuse. Incorrect migrations cause work for the community of the target site, they have to close the question in order to reject the migration.

Comment: I think that if that's the reason it should be possible for users to migrate their own questions that have been flagged for migration. Because my question has been flagged by 5 other users who think that it belongs on Super User (there's a yellow box on the bottom where it says "put on hold as off-topic etc"). If only flagged questions can be migrated by the person who asked them, it would limit the risk for mistakes and abuse.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Sounds like a feature request. You could post it, but I'm not sure if you'll get much support for it (due to the reasons I mentioned).

Comment: @DonaldDuck no one voted to migrate your question.  There is a close reason that suggests Super User as a site for general computing questions and that is what was used here.

Comment: @Stijn OK, see [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338422/allow-users-to-migrate-their-own-question-if-the-question-has-flags)

Answer (score 3):

While you cannot *move* the question to another Stack Exchange site, you may be able to re-post your own question to another site.  You will *only* be able to do this if the question does not already have an accepted or upvoted answer (see [How can a post be deleted?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/328484), particularly the section on "When *can’t* I delete my own post?" for more details).

It is in your own best interest to be proactive on doing this on your own, to avoid unnecessary action by other Stack Overflow users.  Specifically, while your question remains "active", you're susceptible to downvotes from other users, which you really want to avoid as much as you can.  Flagging for a Moderator to migrate will not necessarily happen quickly, and can even take days to complete if the Moderator queue is long or your request happens on a weekend or holiday.

The steps necessary to do this yourself are:

1. delete the question from Stack Overflow <sup>1</sup>
2. copy the entire text of the original question
3. past the entire text of the original question
4. edit the text to suit the guidelines of the target site
5. submit the new (copied) post

It is very important that you first *delete the question from Stack Overflow*, to prevent cross-posted questions; cross-posts are strongly discouraged.  Refer to [Is it OK to cross-post a question between non-Stack Exchange and Stack Exchange website?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266053/is-it-ok-to-cross-post-a-question-between-non-stack-exchange-and-stack-exchange) for more information.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>If your original question has downvotes, these will be counted in your permanent question record on StackOverflow, even after the question is deleted; there's nothing really that you can do about that.  The sooner you *delete* the question from StackOverflow, the sooner you eliminate the opportunity for (additional) downvotes.</sub>

Comment: I can't delete it from Stack Overflow because it has an answer ("Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted; flag it for moderator attention instead.").

Comment: Very true.  Since the question wasn't linked, I didn't realize that was the case here.  I'll amend the answer to reflect that.  :)

Comment: @DonaldDuck You might find some help here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/328484.  If the answer is upvoted or accepted, the question cannot be deleted, but you might be able to remedy that situation.