# Allow users to migrate their own question if the question has flags

Tags: feature-request, flags, migration, migrated-questions

Due to reasons explained in [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338416/can-i-myself-move-my-own-question-to-another-site/338419?noredirect=1#comment414851_338419), users aren't allowed to migrate their own questions to other Stack Exchange sites (to prevent mistakes and abuse). I would like it to be possible for users to migrate their own question when other users have flagged the question as off-topic because it belongs on another site. For example, one of my questions has the following flag raised by 5 users:

> "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User." – Martin Prikryl, Pang, Zheyuan Li, techraf, Dmitry

I would like questions with such flags to be able to be migrated to Super User by the user who asked them, since the flags are proofs that the migration wouldn't be a mistake or abuse.

Comment: Migration is overrated. Users already have the ability to post a question on a different site and close/delete the off-topic copy. This should *not* be automated for them. They need to go to the other site to see if their question is on-topic there.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I can't delete the off-topic copy since it has an up-voted answer.

Comment: Check again. It only had one upvote, so you could have taken care of that yourself.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> ... when other users have flagged the question as off-topic because it belongs on another site

I think you are mistaking the intent of that close reason.  It is not to tell you that **your question** belongs on another site (although, I can understand your confusion).  That close reason is design to inform you that questions about general computing are off-topic on Stack Overflow.  It also advises you there is another site in the Stack Exchange network that may be more suitable such questions.

So no, having a question closed with this specific reason is not proof that your question belongs on Super User, in fact it is quite the opposite because users with close vote powers can actually directly migrate questions to Super User with a migration vote.  If users actually felt it was more appropriate for Super User, they would vote directly for migration, and not use this close reason.

This close reason is used on any question about general computer, software, and hardware, so it is frequently used on low quality questions.  Permitting users to directly migrate their own questions closed using this reason would cause users to migrate their own bad questions to other sites and force a 2nd community to close the question.